# If $\{f_n \}$ is a sequence of integrable function on $R$ , and $\{ f_n \} $ converges to a measurable function $f$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of integrable function on $R$ (a function $g$ is integrable means that $\int_R g \,dx \lt \infty$). And $f_n $ converges uniformly to a measurable function $f$ , means that for any $\epsilon$ ,there exist $N$ , and when $n \ge N$ , we have $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt \epsilon$$ for every $x \in R $ . If we imposed some other properties of $f$ or $f_n$ (not the condition of Fatou or dominated convergence theorem) , can we prove or disprove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_R f_n(x) \, dx = \int_R f(x) \, dx \ \ \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  \text{         (1)}$$ 
My attempt :
a) If we do not assume the uniform convegence , then  (1) might not hold , just consider the the characteristic funtion of $(n,+\infty)$

b) If we assume the uniform convergence , and also assume that $f$ is integrable , then $(1)$ might not hold , consider the function $f_n=\frac 1n $ whenever $x \in (0,n)$ and $f_n=0$ otherwise . Then $f_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly but LHS of (1) is equal to $1$ while the RHS of (1) is equal to $0$ .

c) If we assume the uniform convergence , and also assume $f,f_n$ are non-negtive function , $f$ is not integrable. Then by Fatou's theorem we can check (1) is right for this condition .

My question: does (1) hold for the following two conditions?
d) The similar condition of c) , but we do not assume $f_n $ is non-negtive .

e) The similar condition of c) , but we do not assume $f_n , f$ are non-negtive

Comment: I am pretty sure $d$ will not hold. Take $f(x)=1/x$ on $[1,\infty)$, and $f_n(x)=1/x$ on $[1,n]$, is $-1/n$ on $[n,n+n\ln(n)]$ and $0$ afterwards.

Comment: I see . Thank you for your help .